# ubuntu 20.4 integrated webcam not working

Tags: drivers, dell

I have clean installed Ubuntu 20.4 on a dell latitude 12 7275 tablet and everything is working well except I cannot locate the webcam or camera anywhere.
`lsusb` does not show the module
Installed guvcview without luck

I was thinking of installing libcamera but wanted to see if there was a quick work around.

Comment: I'm afraid this is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1812114). There is no quick workaround and at the end of the bug comments `libcamera` is mentioned as a possible solution,

Comment: Thank you ill try and install libcamera and see if it works

Comment: I also have this issue on my Lenovo S340. The device is detected but not working. FYI:It worked for a few weeks after a Clean install 20.4, but later it stopped working